# how i can add Range Field in Ursina Engin in a smole window

Tags: python, ursina

[image]

I need to add a element like this in my ursina project
to select a number betwen 1000 and 1 Million

Comment: Depending on which specific values you need, you might want to add the log values to emphasize smaller numbers, otherwise they take up only a tiny portion of your slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Slider`:

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()
slider = Slider(1000, 1000000)
app.run()
```